# Como extraer información con substring desde una variable C#

Tags: c#, substring

Para comenzar primero estoy obteniendo el atributo desde un archivo xml de la siguiente manera:

```
XmlDocument xmlInfo = new XmlDocument();
xmlInfo.LoadXml(docInfo);

XmlElement root = xmlInfo.DocumentElement;
if(root.HasAttribute("orgname"))
{
    string xmlInfoString = root.GetAttribute("orgname");
}
```

Lo que deseo es obtener por medio de un substring, cierta información que contiene la variable `xmlInfoString`. Haciendo uso del debug en la variable `xmlInfoString` esta contiene el valor `usuario.png`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo extraer y almacenar en una variable el formato, quiero decir el `.png`, hay que tener en cuenta que el formato puede cambiar dependiendo del valor que obtenga la variable `xmlInfoString` puede ser `.PDF` o `.JPG` diferentes formatos a tener en cuenta.

**Importante:**

Adicional a esto el subtring es necesario que se recorra de atrás para adelante para que en el caso de que la variable obtenga un valor como `prueba.desarrollo.pdf` solo se extraiga lo que esta detrás del ultimo punto, es decir el `.pdf`

**Actualización:**

Haciendo uso de `LastIndexOf`, me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La variable `xmlInfoString` debes declararla fuera del `if`, el error que muestras en la imagen es porque esa variable solo existe dentro del `if`, tendrias que tener `string xmlInfoString;` antes del `if` y dentro del `if` solo asignarle el valor

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es el método [Path.GetExtension()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netcore-3.1) que se encuentra en [System.IO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netcore-3.1). Este método te devuelve la extensión del nombre de fichero que le indiques, sin necesidad de hacer nada más.

```
using System.IO;
// ...
var fileName = "prueba.desarrollo.pdf";
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName); // -> devolvería '.pdf'
```

Si es una necesidad usar `Substring()`, y por lo que respecta al error que te da en su uso, es porque la variable `xmlInfoString` está declarada dentro de un `if`, y estás intentando acceder a ella desde fuera. Declárala antes del `if` y modifícala dentro y no te dará ningún error.